# 'UNIQUE constraint failed: main_chatroom.admin_id' when creating new object in django

Tags: python, django, backend

it only happens when I create new chatroom with the same admin
this is what I wrote in my models.py

```
class ChatRoom(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, unique=True,
                          default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=True)

    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Membership')
    admin = models.ForeignKey(
        User, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='admin')
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Membership(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, unique=True,
                          default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    chatroom = models.ForeignKey(ChatRoom, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=False, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['user', 'chatroom']]
```

when i write this in the shell:

```
from .main.models import ChatRoom,Membership
from django.contrib.auth.models import User         
user  = User.objects.get(username = 'someone')
chatroom = ChatRoom(admin = user, name = 'something')
chatroom.save()
chatroom2 = ChatRoom(admin = user, name = 'somethingElse')
chatroom2.save()
```

after i save chatroom2 i get this error : `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: main_chatroom.admin_id`
can anyone help me?

Comment: You made `unique_together = [['user', 'chatroom']]`. This thus means that if the `chatroom` is the same, and the `user` is the same, this raises an error.

Comment: I just removed the 'meta' class and tried to create new chatroom with the same admin but the same error has been raised, this will make sense if I create new membership with the same user and chatroom

Comment: the constraint is handled by the database, so you need to make migrations and migrate the database properly.

Comment: when I try  'makemigrations' I get 'No changes detected'

Answer (score 0):

so it turned out that i did something that made all migrations does not have any affect on the database
so i created new project and copied all my code to the new project( yes i know this is not the right way to do things but it was the easiest way for me)  and everything now works great